# How to assign key to bitmap using HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, keyvaluepair

In global definition I have declared: `private HashMap<String, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();`

In other part of my code, I connect to server and get my required info. Two of then are image address (url) and image id. after that I download image and I want to assign it its own Id. This is my code:

```
private LinkedList<Bitmap> getFlagImages() {
    InputStream is= null;
    LinkedList<Bitmap> llBitmap = new LinkedList<Bitmap>();


    for(int i = 0; i < flag.getTeamLogo44x44().size(); i++) {
        String urlstr = flag.getTeamLogo44x44().get(i);

        try {
            HttpGet httpRequest   = new HttpGet(urlstr);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
            is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            llBitmap.add(bm);
            map.put(flag.getTeamId().get(i), bm);  // *Crash happens here

        }catch ( MalformedURLException e ){
            Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "Invalid URL passed" + urlstr );
        }catch ( IOException e ){
            Log.d( "RemoteImageHandler", "fetchImage IO exception: " + e );
        }finally{
            if(is != null) {
                try{
                    is.close();
                } catch(IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }

    return llBitmap;        
}
```

When I run, the application crashes and logcat shows Null Pointer Exception and points to line `map.put(flag.getTeamId().get(i), bm);`

Any suggestion would be  appreciated.

// **Update**,
Also I used `map.put(flag.getTeamId().get(i), Bitmap.createBitmap(bm));` but the result was same.

Comment: Please include a stack trace.  In all liklihood, `flag.getTeamId().get(i)` is returning `null`.

Comment: @cheeken - `HashMap` allows the `null` key though. My guess would be `getTeamId()` is returning `null`.

Comment: @PaulBellora Ah, very good point!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `flag.getTeamId()` is null, or, like cheeken said, `flag.getTeamId.get(i)` is null

You could try using assertions like
assert (flag.getTeamId() != null)
assert (flag.getTeamId().get(i) != null)

Now run your jvm with the -ea flag (short for enable assertions)

Comment: i'm sure it has result because i checked it. Now the problem solved with changing mentioned line with map.put(flag.getTeamId().get(i), Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight())); Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
map.put(flag.getTeamId().get(i), bm);
```

to

```
map.put(flag.getTeamId().get(i), Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight()));
```

and its ok, now. but I have no idea why the first one didn't work!!!

Comment: That doesn't make sense - the value that is `put` shouldn't matter, even if it was `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found your answer. However, you might consider having your map take `WeakReference<Bitmap>` as a value instead. That is,

```
Map<Integer, WeakReference<Bitmap>>
```

By keeping a weak reference, you ensure garbage collection will work as expected later on.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Key comes from server, I'm not sure it is always integer. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Well unless the server is sending you a `BigInteger`, I think you should be OK :D